# how to tell cloud formation init it shall use a specific repository by installing yum packages

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Im using [AWS::CloudFormation::Init](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-init.html) to deploy services and packages within a AWS EC2-Instance. By default, Cloud Formation ist using AWS's repository which installs old versions like PHP 5.4.16 in my case. I told [cfn-init](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-init.html) to install remi and epel repositories but it seams I have to tell yum the same. In a bash I would do this like:

```
sudo yum --enablerepo=remi,remi-php71 install httpd php php-common
```

Sure, I could do the same in the UserData section as well but want to avoid as long as there's no way in configSets possible.

```
"install_apache2": {
"packages": {
    "rpm":{
        "remi" : "http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-7.rpm",
        "epel" : "https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm"
    },
    "yum":  {
        "php": [],
        "php-mysql": [],
        "php-mcrypt": [],
        "php-gd": [],
        "php-pear": [],
        "httpd": [],
        "nano": [],
        "git": []
    }
},
```

here ist a short cut from my cfn-init-cmd.log:

```
P7691 [INFO]    ===============================================================================
P7691 [INFO]     Package          Arch   Version         Repository                        Size
P7691 [INFO]    ===============================================================================
P7691 [INFO]    Installing:
P7691 [INFO]     git              x86_64 1.8.3.1-20.el7  rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases 4.4 M
P7691 [INFO]     httpd            x86_64 2.4.6-88.el7    rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases 1.2 M
P7691 [INFO]     nano             x86_64 2.3.1-10.el7    rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases 440 k
P7691 [INFO]     php              x86_64 5.4.16-46.el7   rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases 1.4 M
P7691 [INFO]     php-gd           x86_64 5.4.16-46.el7   rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases 128 k
P7691 [INFO]     php-mcrypt       x86_64 5.4.16-7.el7    epel                              20 k
P7691 [INFO]     php-mysql        x86_64 5.4.16-46.el7   rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases 102 k
P7691 [INFO]     php-pear         noarch 1:1.9.4-21.el7  rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases 357 k
```